# Proving $d(x,A)\le d(x,y)+d(y,A) $

Tags: metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

This proof should be easy but I get stuck because I don't know how to deal with the infimum in this case.

I want to prove that
$$d(x,A)\le d(x,y)+d(y,A) $$
with
$$d(x,A)=\text{inf}(\{d(x,a):a\in A\})$$

**My attempt:**
Let $y\in X$. We have $d(x,a)\le d(x,y)+d(y,a) $ for any $a\in A$.

How can I get the inequality for the infimum from this?

Comment: Show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ you have $d(x,A) \leqslant d(x,y) + \bigl(d(y,A) + \varepsilon\bigr)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all $a\in A$ we have by triangle inequality

$$d(x,A)\le d(x,a)\le d(x,y)+d(y,a)$$
so 
$$d(x,A)-d(x,y)\le d(y,a),\;\forall a\in A$$
hence
$$d(x,A)-d(x,y)\le d(y,A)$$

Comment: You seem to have used $d(y,a)\le d(y,A)$...

Comment: Otherwise, how can you justify the last step? Just because $d(x,A)-d(x,y)\le d(y,a),\;\forall a\in A$ does that mean that $d(x,A)-d(x,y)\le d(y,A)$? There may not exist an $a\in A$ such that $d(y,A)=d(y,a)$...

Comment: @XicoSimThe answer is correct. Look at the definition of the infimum.

Comment: @juniven That's what I've done, and $d(y,A)\le d(y,a)$, not the other way around.

Comment: I had this problem with proofs like these numerous times: one can have $d(y,A)< d(y,a) \forall a\in A$, so the last step does not seem legit to me.

Comment: @XicoSim If you have $C \leqslant d(y,a)$ for all $a\in A$, then you also have $C \leqslant \inf\limits_{a\in A} d(y,a)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, That does not seem obvious to me, though, because of what I said on my previous comment: the infimum of a set can be smaller than all the elements of the set, so guaranteeing $C\le b \,\,\forall b \in B$ does not seem to guarantee that $ C\le \text{inf}B$

Comment: @XicoSim Okay, $d(x,A)-d(x,y)$ serves as a lower bound of the set $\{d(y,a):a\in A\}$. So , by the definition of $d(y,A)$, the last line holds.

Comment: @XicoSim If $\inf B < D$, then in particular there is a $b\in B$ with $b < D$. So if $C \leqslant b$ for all $b\in B$, then $C \leqslant \inf B$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $d(y,A)+\epsilon$ can not be a lower bound of the set $\{d(y,a):a\in A\}$. Thus, there exists $w\in A$ such that

$$d(y,w)<d(y,A)+\epsilon.$$

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
d(x,A)&\leq d(x,w)\\
&\leq d(x,y)+d(y,w)\\
&<d(x,y)+d(y,A)+\epsilon.
\end{align}
$$
We have shown that 
$$d(x,A)<d(x,y)+d(y,A)+\epsilon\quad\text{for all }\epsilon>0.$$
Thus,
$$d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,A).$$